# .net Change EntityFramework.dll to match my .net version

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So to solve another problem I inspected whether my version of EntityFramework.dll matches my version of .net, and it seems it doesn't. I am using .net 4.5 and my Object Browser tells me my version of EF is `\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll`. That seems to imply that I have the EF for .net 4.0, not 4.5.

I don't know if this is the cause of the problem I'm dealing with but I want to try to update it, and it's proved extremely stubborn about not changing. I have tried the following:

- Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force followed by Install-Package EntityFramework
- Remove package from my `references` and then added the package from somewhere that I have the most version for .net 4.5
- Manually delete the EntityFramwork from my bin and lib folder and copied it from somewhere that I have the correct version

No matter what I do, I still get the same version of EF. How do I change this?

I should add that in my packages.config file, the version of EF I want is referenced:

```
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net451" />
```

However when I look at the properties of the EntityFramework.dll in Object browser I'm told that it's the version for 4.0, as can be seen in the picture below.[image: EntityFramework version]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows you not a version of EF that you reference on, but the version of runtime.

You can check [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx) and you can see that for all **.net4+** it will show Runtime Version 4.0.30319.

If you want to you EF for .net 4.5, you just need to make sure that you have a reference to a correspond folder under you 'packages' folder.

like: `\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll`

Comment: Thank you. I understand that that's what I want. I do not understand the actual steps to make it happen. I have removed the package, then added a reference to the package in the right place, but I still see a reference to the other one.

Comment: As I said above, I tried to do it both ways. I tried every way that I could think of and I still have the wrong one.

Comment: if you doing it manually, it's should have a right one. Only if you missed the reference.
If you doing it through package manager, then it should use the version which is targeted by your project (you can check this in project properties).

Answer (score 1):

The version numbering is a bit [odd since 4.5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2014/12/23/identifying-the-net-version-you-are-running-2-0-4-5-4-5-1-or-4-5-2/):

```
.NET 4.0    4.0.30319.0 to 4.0.30319.17000
.NET 4.5    4.0.30319.17001 to 4.0.3019.18400
.NET 4.5.1  4.0.30319.18401 to 4.0.30319.34000
.NET 4.5.2  4.0.30319.34000 and higher
```

Comment: This is useful information. As you can see above, I have runtime version 4.0.30319, which is the version for 4.0. So I still can't see how to change it.

Comment: 30319 could be anything. You need more digits to figure out what exactly it is

Comment: How would I go about getting more digits?

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your `NuGet` version? You should update your version of `NuGet` then try again. You can find the download at http://www.nuget.org/.

Comment: I just updated my nuget to the newest version and repeated the steps above. I still have the wrong version of EntityFramework.

Comment: one more thing you should do that is manually download `entityframework` from here-http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework and reinstall it.

Comment: The problem is I have the right entityframework. I can see the thing right there in my file explorer. I just cannot get my project to reference it.